# Stupid physics in cartoons

Tags: visible-light

I have never really thought about some of the horrible thought (or was it intentional?)physics in old cartoons (for me, I'm 14). The main show im talking about is this stupid one called something like Danny Demon or something. He basically has super powers like intangibility, and invisibility. If light bounces off of objects, and hits your retina, and that's how you see, how does he see? The light would go straight through his retina!
BTW this is not really a question, Im not even sure if it qualifies as physics

Comment: You can make it a real physics question by asking it this way "Is a true invisibility cloak possible?". The answer is "no" for a variety of reasons, one being the one that you mentioned. I am sure we have questions and good answers about this already, though.

Comment: just quick question, is it normal for a 14 yr old, (8th grade honors physical science, near middle of year, were currently studying alpha/beta/gamma radiation) to kinda be good with physics?

Comment: If you are me, it would have been normal. I am pretty sure that most folks here who have done physics professionally were excellent at it, even in eight grade. Having said that... be very careful with this... you have absolutely no idea how good the other eight graders are that will greatly exceed you in life. Some of them are already better than I ever will be. :-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about the vision of a hypothetical superhero not physics

Comment: kk please do, im starting to feel embarrassed I even started talking about this

Comment: Nothing to be embarrassed, the question simply needs to be put in a right way.

Comment: im just saying im embarrassed that i even mentioned it

Comment: I asked myself this too and came to resolution, that "superpowers" are just old plain "magic" and so finding physical base for it is not the right way. Some stories just needs something happened to work and so it happens. Sometime author just say "it is a magic", sometimes he puts in some lame excuses "it is too hight science", sometimes he even do not care "it just happened". If the story is good and listeners are happy, they will forgive him and play with him "yes, the glass shoe was just so small, that only one girl in whole kingdom would fit it and none child, no questions". Sometimes not.

Comment: being devils advocate, sometimes a visible compound (say table salt or sugar) becomes nearly invisible to human eye when dissoved in a solvent (say water). Maybe this super guy somehow dissolves in spacetime.

Comment: I would be a little cautious about closing this as off topic. Movie superpower questions are about physics in a broad sense. We get questions where people seriously want to know how superheros do it. Mostly they have so little knowledge of physics they don't understand that movies are fiction. We can set them a little straighter. This question is a giant step better than most. He is already thinking clearly about difficulties in explaining it with physics. +1 for that.